# Add PayPal Donate button to C++ application

Tags: 12.04, application-development

Is it possible to add PayPal Donate button to any application which I develop for Ubuntu. I'm asking it for C++ because I'm C++ developer.

Comment: Is this a programming question? Do you need a how-to? Or does it have to do with legal issues concerning the use of paypal's logo?

Comment: I'm asking if it's possible to do under Ubuntu. If it is, can you show me where can I get more information.

Comment: Voted to close since this is a programming question and not so much related to Ubuntu. You have a better chance at stackoverflow

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of course you can add a paypal donate button. Just add a normal button and connect it to a function that launches the default browser (you may use the `xdg-open` application (`xdg-open url_here`)) to the donate page.